# Access array inside a php function

Tags: php, arrays, function, global-variables, global

Access array with same name `$userinfo` inside a php function

```
<?php 
    $userinfo['name'] = "bob";
    $userinfo['lastname'] = "johnson";

    function displayinfo() {
//not working 
    echo $userinfo['name']
//global also not working 
    echo global $userinfo['lastname'];

    }
    displayinfo();

?>
```

how to acess the arrays in the `$userinfo` var since it has more than one array in the same variable name?

```
echo $userinfo['name']
//global also not working 
echo global $userinfo['lastname'];
```

both do not working.

Comment: Better to pass the array into the function as global is generally discouraged

Comment: could you give a working example?

Comment: `echo $GLOBALS['userinfo']['lastname'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, for more details [PHP Variable Scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

```
function displayinfo() {
  global $userinfo;
  echo $userinfo['lastname'];
}
```

Working example : https://3v4l.org/5l5NZ

Comment: This is what I was looking, Thank you, I will implement in my function now.

Comment: @OtávioBarreto glad to help you!

Answer (score 5):

I recommend [passing the variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) to the function:

```
function displayinfo($userinfo) {
  echo $userinfo['name'];
}

$userinfo['name'] = "bob";
$userinfo['lastname'] = "johnson";

displayinfo($userinfo);
```

See:
[PHP global in functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions)
[Are global variables in PHP considered bad practice? If so, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why)

Comment: Ok why it's better than use global?

Comment: There are several potential reasons listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5166527/924299). You can use `global`, but things might get messy depending on your context.